# Derivate of $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ when $f$ is not continuous.

Tags: integration, derivatives

Can someone help with this : I know that for example if $f(t)=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}(t)$, then $$F(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)d t=x$$ for every $x$ (et not almost every where). And $F'(x)=f(x)$ for almost every $x$, but $F'(x)=1$ for all $x$. Now, I have a function $f(t)$ that looks nicer that $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$ but $F$ looks to have less regularity. Take $f(t)=sgn(t)$ the sign function s.t. $f(0)=0$. So, this looks nicer than $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$. But then $F(x)=\int_{-1}^x f(t)dt=|x|$. So, now $F$ is not derivable everywhere but only almost every where, and we have now $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ but $x\neq 0$.

I don't understand why with a nicer function, $F$ is not derivable everywhere. Am I mistaken something ?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't miss anything, and your argument is perfectly correct. The reason (as surprising as it looks), it's that $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$ is a nicer function than the sign function in the sense that $f:=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$ has a continuous representative (i.e. a continuous function $\bar f$ s.t. $\bar f=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$ a.e. (for instance, $\bar f(x)=1$ for all $x$), whereas the sign function has not. So, in general, if $f$ has a continuous representative $\bar f$, and $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm d t,$$
then $$F'(x)=\bar f(x),$$ for all $x$. If $f$ has no continuous representative, you don't have better than $F$ is derivable a.e. and  $$F'(x)=f(x)\quad \text{a.e.}$$

---

For such a result, look at theorem 3.11 in chapter 3 of Stein and Shakarchi books : Real-Analysis.